# Windows 11 - You do not have permission to access <machine name> \\<machine name>\share works perfectly well

Tags: windows, networking, windows-11, network-shares

On one windows 11 (22H2) pc (serverpc), that I support, when trying to access \clientpc1 You do not have permission to access clientpc1 is displayed.  The target machine is running windows 10 with 22H2.

From another PC (clientpc2 also windows 10 22H2) on the network it works fine when exploring to \clientpc, I see the shared printer and 3 folder shares.

Although from serverpc if I access \clientpc1\share1  that works I get the list of files, can read and write to the files in the folder. Trying to go up 1 level just gives the "You don't have permission" message.

I cannot see what this is. I've tried a reboot, ipconfig /flushdns,netsh int ip reset & netsh winsock reset, nbtstat /r.

The network is just a 3 machine workgroup, not a domain.
All the machines are set to Private, Password Protected Sharing is On , the firewall is set to allow SMB and I've also switched the firewall off, and the shared folders have permissions to allow Everyone full control. (though the issue isn't being able to access the shares, as I can do that as I mentioned above, it is accessing the \clientpc1 which should display all the shared devices and folders from that machine.)

I don't have any issues with my office network which I have a couple of win 10 machines and a win 11 pc.

Anyone got any ideas on this please?

Thanks

The image below is what to see.

[image: This is what I want to display and it isn't happening]

Comment: Make sure:  Network Discovery, File and Print Sharing, password protected sharing are all ON and the connection is Private, not Public. You may need to ensure the target folder is permitted to the source computer.

Comment: @John 

All of that has already been checked.  (I've edited the main post)
I can access the shares if I type the share name at the end of the path, I just cannot view \\clientpc1 to see what the shared resources are.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to access a complete drive without naming it has been deprecated and gone.

What you can do is go to the Drive Properties, Sharing Tab, give it a name like DriveC, give it a password.

Then click on Advanced Properties and share to specific users or Everyone.

That will work - I use it.

[image: Share a Drive]

=============

Your added picture suggests there are issues despite correct settings. If you have issues with specific sharing, you can try a Windows 11 Repair or back up and reinstall Windows 11.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to share the entire C:  though  I need to be able to see the shared devices (mainly a printer) that is marked as shared on the target machine.   As I have said the folder shares are accessible and I have full control over them if i access them directly i.e. \\clientpc1\share1<- this works fine. The reason I want to be able to see all the shared devices is to install a printer from the share.  Settings keeps closing when I click on Add device.  (I suspect I'll need to reinstall windows on the PC as I cannot see a reason why settings just exits when add device is clicked).

Comment: I added the Repair and / or Reinstall to my answer. You had indicated the drive in your answer which is why I showed the sharing. If the settings do not work, Repair  (and possibly Reinstall) is likely required (else too much looking around for a specific cause).

Comment: Yeah.  I'm wondering if that is needed.